# Stuck on typescript generic signature for GroupBy function

Tags: typescript

Having some trouble after a few hours wrapping my head around what I'm doing wrong with this TS signature.

**I'm writing a group by function:**

```
const group = <T>(items: T[], fn: (item: T) => T[keyof T]) => {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => {
    const prop = fn(next) as unknown as string;
    return {
      ...prev,
      [prop]: prev[prop] ? [...prev[prop], next] : [next],
    };
  }, {} as any);
};

group(data, (item) => item.type);
```

**The return type gives me this:**

```
const group: <Item>(items: Item[], fn: (item: Item) => string) => any
```

**What I want is this:**

```
const group: <Item>(items: Item[], fn: (item: Item) => string) => { admin: Item[], user: Item[] }
```

**Here's the data structure:**

```
interface User {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

const data: User[] = [
  { type: 'admin', name: 'One' },
  { type: 'user', name: 'Two' },
  { type: 'admin', name: 'Three' },
];
```

I have tried something like this (with the object passed into reduce) but it gives me an error and I'm sure sure what the 'fix' is:

```
{} as { [key: T[keyof T]: T[]] }
```

[Here's a TS Playground with the running code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnJgCeADhAFzIDOYUoA5gNz7IhwYXW0PMC%20uuBAHsQNZABM4YOJXQQMAbQC6yALzIFLbIVKcA5DCFDxegDSt2%20gArAAXrbh7kvU1p1lKe8XRABrMxYcngDCQjAwEBBOLm7EHsgGRibmbEEJABJCYMgAIkL00a5KzIIiYvRQQgCuJGrIADwAKgB8ABTAmFSUjcrmMCCU7ZjdAJRqzcg9vhBEYZNKY6oTeARQEGBVUCDIHfJUAHRr4lVIra0kawBuKRAAHmCLyywEwqLZF0K16v2tIHcPyDgVGQVT8ICEAHdtkCuD4mM9kGsNlscAiCPsMRcINc0RoPiQlJQsZcFPiVAB%20DQY-bE0mVAk3e4qSgKP5M1wEAi8Zhc8zYXiA4FwEBEEZ8EqvKhCAA2EH20vyrQq1RIrUk0nMQ3kjx2mH2cQgIzFQA)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that "admin" and "user" can only be obtained from the values of the data array (possible values of `data[number]['type']`).
TypeScript by default won't assume much from the values other than the values are strings. (The situation for 'type' and 'name' is different as they are obtained from keys)

But if you use `as const` for an array, TypeScript will infer more restrictions for the values as well.
Assuming the valid values of `User['type']` is limited, it's possible to restrict it as shown below:

```js
let PossibleUserTypes = ['admin', 'user'] as const;  

interface User {
  type: typeof PossibleUserTypes[number];
  name: string;
}

const data: User[] = [
  { type: 'admin', name: 'One' },
  { type: 'user', name: 'Two' },
  { type: 'admin', name: 'Three' },
];

const group = <T extends User, U extends string>(items: T[], fn: (item: T) => U) => {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => {
    const prop = fn(next)
    return {
      ...prev,
      [prop]: prev[prop] ? [...prev[prop], next] : [next],
    };
  }, {} as {[x in U] : T[] } );
};
let temp = group(data, (item) => item.type);
console.log(temp);
/*
inferred typing: 
let temp: {
    admin: User[];
    user: User[];
}
*/
```

If you remove the 'as const' part, the output will just become just `{ [x: string]: User[];}`, as it doesn't assume what the values of `x` (from the value for 'type') could be restricted to.

n.b. Instead of `type: typeof PossibleUserTypes[number];` you can also use `type: 'admin' | 'user'` directly; the thing is, it's no longer just "any string" like in your original code.

Another alternative is using `{} as Record<U,T[]>` (here `temp` will be inferred to be `Record<'user'|'admin', User[]>` which still allows you to get code completion from `temp.` to `temp.admin` and `temp.user`), and again if you remove `as const` you lose the restriction (so it's not just `.admin` and `.user` anymore).

One may attempt using `as const` for the `data` array rather than the `PossibleUserTypes`, but then the resulting type will be very complex (you can check it out yourself):

```js
const data  = [
  { type: 'admin', name: 'One' },
  { type: 'user', name: 'Two' },
  { type: 'admin', name: 'Three' },
] as const 
 

const group = <T, U extends string>(items: Readonly<T[]>, fn: (item: T) => U) => {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => {
    const prop = fn(next)
    return {
      ...prev,
      [prop]: prev[prop] ? [...prev[prop], next] : [next],
    };
  }, {} as {[x in U] : T[] } );
};
let temp = group(data, (item) => item.type);
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer, this is really great stuff. Have an amazing day!

Answer (score 0):

In your function signature you do not specify the return type of the function.
You just need to make the return of type T like this :

```
const group = <T>(items: T[], fn: (item: T) => T[keyof T]):T => { return items.reduce((prev, next) => {
const prop = fn(next) as unknown as string;
return {
  ...prev,
  [prop]: prev[prop] ? [...prev[prop], next] : [next],
};}, {} as any);};
console.log(group<Item>(data, (item) => item.type));
```

See this Typescript playground [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnJgCeADhAFzIDOYUoA5gNz7IhwYXW0PMC%20uuBAHsQNZABM4YOJXQQMAbQC6yALzIFLbIVKcA5DCFDxegDSt2%20gArAAXrbh7kvU1p1lKe8XRABrMxYcngDCQjAwEBBOLm7EHsgGRibmbEEJABJCYMgAIkL00a5KzIIiYvRQQgCuJGrIADwAKgB8ABTAmFSUjcrmMCCU7ZjdAJRqzcg9vhBEYZNKI93jOCxQEGBVUCDIHfJUAHRr4lVIra0kawBuKRAAHmBjqhN4BATCotkXQrXq-a0gdweyDgVGQVT8ICEAHdtiCuD4mCwCGsNlsVq9XvssRcINcka8FF8SEpKDjLoTKsTkAB%20DRY-ZkinfJQ3e4qSgKAFs1wY3jMAguHC8YGguAgIgjPgld5UIQAGwg%20zl%20VaFWqJHqcgwbUk0nMQ3kjwmuww%20ziEBGkqAA)

> Referring to your comment I have changed a little bit the code.
> [check here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnJgCeADhAFzIDOYUoA5gNz7IhwYXW0PMC%20uAhAHsQNZABM4YOJXQQMAbQC6yALzIFLbIVKcA5DCFDxegDSt2%20gArAAXrbh7kvU1p1lKe8XRABrMxYcngDCQjAwEBBOLm7EHsgGRibmbEEJABJCYMgAIkL00a5KzLjCotn0UEIAriRqyAAUwJhUspjK5jAglE2YbfLIAJRqAHxcPvRDlNoKvhBEyJQ0E0r9iiq8BKpjeARQEGDVUCDIzfJUAHT74tVIDQ0k%20wBuKRAAHmDD2zgsBGVijyEdSW3BAk3UXQaIHen2QcCo4wYBGQzGRyH2h2OPzRBAueMeEBev2RCkBJFWyAJT1JVXJyAA-Bo8RcqTSgUpXh8VJQFNCuchXGjeKjnOZsJt4TgNHMFiCVmtlM4hnwSv8hAAbCAXdX5BqVGokBqSaTmXryL5jM4YC5xCCDQaMIA)
> A returned type must be a static type.

Comment: Thanks Mohamad, this isn't quite what I'm looking for though - if you hover over the function call you'll see => Item as the return type, when it should be { admin: Item[], user: Item[] }

Comment: The way you want it to be is fairly cuzzy. Because you want to use a Value of a variable as a returned type! when TypeScript engine shows you the retuned type, when you hover the mouse over the function,  it does not have any access to any runtime variables. So maybe you need to change the way you want it.  @StephenJenkins